# Can't pass basic authethication via curl

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl, spring-webflux, basic-authentication

i try to add basic authentication to my Spring Boot non-web application.
Tests works fine with @WithMockUser annotation but i cant get proper cURL with correct (as it seems) credentials.
My security configuration:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Value("${application.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${application.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.csrf().disable().authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/endpoint/v1/**").authenticated()
                .and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails details = User
                .withUsername(user)
                .password(password)
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(details);
    }

}
```

First attempt was with BCryptPasswordEncoder (and not working) but i get rid of that for simplify the problem.

I use curl like this:

```
curl -I --user user1:pass localhost:9094/endpoint/v1/health
```

And i run my application with the same arguments, but still get:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
transfer-encoding: chunked
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/endpoint/v1")
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationController {

    @GetMapping("/health")
    @Timed
    public Mono<String> health() {
        log.info("Health ok");
        return Mono.just(String.format(STATUS, "ok"));
    }
}
```

I try postman but same results.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**@Update**

Debug logs from terminal when i try to login with proper credentials:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.488+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] New http connection, requesting read","logger_name":"reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations","thread_name":"reactor-http-epoll-3","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.488+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}","logger_name":"reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers","thread_name":"reactor-http-epoll-3","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.498+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] Increasing pending responses, now 1","logger_name":"reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations","thread_name":"reactor-http-epoll-3","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.498+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@7f908d6a","logger_name":"reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer","thread_name":"reactor-http-epoll-3","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.499+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[c6f8daa9-2] HTTP HEAD \"/endpoint/v1/health\"","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter","thread_name":"reactor-http-epoll-3","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.500+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Created new WebSession.","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.server.session.DefaultWebSessionManager","thread_name":"boundedElastic-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.511+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[c6f8daa9-2] Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter","thread_name":"boundedElastic-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.512+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] Last HTTP response frame","logger_name":"reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations","thread_name":"boundedElastic-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.512+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] No sendHeaders() called before complete, sending zero-length header","logger_name":"reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations","thread_name":"boundedElastic-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.514+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] Decreasing pending responses, now 0","logger_name":"reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations","thread_name":"reactor-http-epoll-3","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-07T09:53:33.514+02:00","@version":"1","message":"[id: 0xc6f8daa9, L:/127.0.0.1:9094 - R:/127.0.0.1:49572] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel","logger_name":"reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations","thread_name":"reactor-http-epoll-3","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"application":"myApp"}
```

Comment: before running cURL, check in the browser if your springboot basic authentication is working, when you access localhost:9094  are you able to login with credentials

Comment: @sanjeevRm, nothing happens when i enter credentials in to form on localhost:9094, the form keep pop out again and again. No difference if i put wrong or correct username/password. Idk how to interpreter this?

Comment: What do you see in logs

Comment: In terminal, where i run my app there's nothing new, last log is "Started application in 4 seconds..."

Comment: Enable dubug logs in the application.

Comment: I update my question with that logs.

Comment: as soon as you provide a custom security configuration you are overriding the defaults. You need to explicitly define that you want basic authentication `.httpBasic(withDefaults())` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#explicit-webflux-security-configuration

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes, that was the problem. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add spring security to an application you automatically get a default security setup, which is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-hello-auto-configuration) in the spring security documentation.

But as soon as you declare a custom security configuration, then you are basically on your own.

What is missing in the above configuration is to explicitly configure that you want `http basic` authentication.

this is done by adding:

```
.httpBasic(withDefaults())
```

You can read about basic auth [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-basic).